# Table Will Not Load/Show CloudKit Data

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, cloudkit

I am using CloudKit to store a few arrays, then use the arrays to fill a table. I am reloading the table, but it will not show any data. It should be connected to iCloud because I am still able to add to the database.

Code is shown below:

```
import UIKit
import CloudKit

var selectedCellName = ""

class explore: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var groupNames = [String]()
    var Group = [CKRecord]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        loadGroups()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return groupNames.count
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "exploreCell")! as UITableViewCell
        // let nameCell = leaderboardInfo[indexPath.row].object(forKey: "Name") as! String
        // let usernameCell = leaderboardInfo[indexPath.row].object(forKey: "Username") as! String
        //let pointsCell = leaderboardInfo[indexPath.row].object(forKey: "Points") as! String
        var nameCellLbl = cell.viewWithTag(100) as! UILabel

        nameCellLbl.text = groupNames[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

Here is the `loadGroups()` function which is used to query the database:

```
 func loadGroups(){
    print("should go")
    // let pred = NSPredicate(format: "Username = %@", usernameText)
    let pred = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Group", predicate: pred)
    let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
    //operation.resultsLimit = CKQueryOperationMaximumResults
    operation.qualityOfService = .default
    operation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record: CKRecord!) in

        if record != nil{

            // need self in front?
            groupNames.append(record.object(forKey: "groupName") as! String)


            //self.tableView.reloadData()
            //print(self.groupNames.count)

        }


      }
    database.add(operation)
    //self.tableView.reloadData()
    // print(leaderboardInfo.count)
}
```

This used to work, and if I made changes I made them months ago so I can't remember. Anyway this is the problem in all of my files where I query the database, but the table won't load it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reloading the table view long before you actually query the data.

Remove the call to `reloadData` in `viewDidLoad`.

In `loadGroups` you need to setup a query completion handler. You need to deal with the possibility that the query completion hander will indicate that there is more data to load.

You should build a new array from the queried data. Don't update `groupNames` until you have all of the data. Then, on the main queue, update `groupNames` with the queried results and then reload the table view.

An even better solution is to add a completion handler to your `loadGroups` method. Then instead of `loadGroups` directly updating `groupNames` and reloading the table view, it simply passes back a new array with all of the query data. Then the caller can update the `groupNames` and reload the table view it the completion block it passes to the call to `loadGroups`.

```
func loadGroups(completion: ((_ groups: [String]) -> Void)) {
    var names = [String]()

    // setup operation
    ...
    operation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record: CKRecord!) in
        if record != nil {
            names.append(record.object(forKey: "groupName") as! String)
        }
    }

    operation.queryCompletionBlock = { (cursor, error) in {
        // properly handle cursor and error

        completion(names)
    }
}
```

Then this can be called from your view controller as:

```
loadGroups() { (names) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        groupNames = names
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

The above is a rough outline. This is not meant to be production ready.

Comment: I added a simple refresh button, which just reloads the table. I believe it should work, but it doesn't, even after I wait a minute

Comment: The problem could be that groupNames is empty...do you see in the loadGroups() function where I say there may be a self in front of the append statement? How do I add that when the function is in a different file?

Comment: See my updated answer for a better solution that works even if `loadGroups` is in a different class.

Comment: I like the new idea. Except I haven't used a completion handler before, do you mind writing the one line I need, then I can put the rest of the code in myself?