# Need to fire completion block immediately after CloudKit query

Tags: arrays, swift, tableview, cloudkit, completionhandler

I'm stuck on the idea of how to write a CloudKit completion block. My issue is I am loading data, then putting the data in a tableView. The problem is I have to refresh the tableView manually with a button instead of it loading the data to it automatically. What I need is a completion block at the end of my query to reload the table data. Below is my query function:

```
func loadGroupPage() {
    print("should go")
    // let pred = NSPredicate(format: "Username = %@", usernameText)
    let pred = NSPredicate(format: "groupName = %@", "\(selectedCellName)")
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Group", predicate: pred)
    let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
    //operation.resultsLimit = CKQueryOperationMaximumResults
    operation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record: CKRecord!) in
       operation.qualityOfService = .default

        if record != nil{

            // setup screen after loading data

            self.recordToUpdate = record

            if creatingNewPost == true{
                print(feed)
                //create new post record (modify record)
                feed.append(postText)
                creatingNewPost = false
                self.saveNewPost()
            }

            self.publicOrPrivate = (record.object(forKey: "PublicOrPrivate") as! String)
            if self.publicOrPrivate == "Public"{
                // public
                //print("you have joined")

            }else if self.publicOrPrivate == "Private"{
                // private
                //print("requestSent")
                // self.sendRequest()
                 self.requests = (record.object(forKey: "Requests") as! Array)
            }
            if self.groupMembs.contains(username) || members.contains(username){
                self.joinBtn.alpha = 0
                // in group
            }else{
                self.joinBtn.alpha = 1
            }
            if self.leaders.contains(username) && self.publicOrPrivate == "Private"{
                // leader
                self.requestsTableView.alpha = 1
            }else{
                self.requestsTableView.alpha = 0
            }
            if self.groupMembs.contains(username) || self.publicOrPrivate == "Public"{
                // leader

                feed = (record.object(forKey: "groupFeed") as! Array)
                print(feed)
            }else{

            }
            self.groupMembs = (record.object(forKey: "memberUsernames") as! Array)

            print(self.groupMembs)
            self.numberOfMembersInGroup = self.groupMembs.count
            self.groupNameLbl.text = selectedCellName
            self.numberOfMembersLbl.text = "\(self.numberOfMembersInGroup) Members"
            self.leaders = (record.object(forKey: "leaders") as! Array)

            //****************************************************
            // this does nothing until I refresh it manually!
            self.requestsTableView.reloadData()
            self.groupFeedTableView.reloadData()
            //****************************************************
            //Need completion block so the above two lines will fire directly after data is done loading!
        }

    }
    database.add(operation)    
}
```

As I documented in the code above, refreshing the table there will not load anything in the actual UI. Can someone please write a completion block that simply reloads the tableView(s) for me?  Thanks!

Comment: This isn't even remotely close to what I showed you in my answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47254502/table-will-not-load-show-cloudkit-data).

Comment: @rmaddy don't worry this is a completely different query. Im not having the array problem anymore. Now it's how do I write a completion for this query that reloads the table (my solution to the last problem didn't involve a completion because I couldn't find any easy to follow notes online)

Comment: My answer to your previous question is the exact same thing you should be doing here. The specifics of the query may be different but the structure is identical.

Comment: @rmaddy so specifically how would I write the completion, because I have no idea what to write and online resources aren't helping me too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

I used the following code to add a completion:

```
operation.queryCompletionBlock = { [unowned self] (cursor, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if error == nil {

                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }
        }
    }
```

Works like a charm!